# Place output of numpy function into diagonal of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to take the row sums of one array and place the output into the diagonals of another array. For performance reasons, I want to use the `out` argument of the `np.sum` function.

```
mat1 = np.array([[0.5, 0.5],[0.6, 0.4]])

mat2 = np.zeros([2,2])

mat3 = np.zeros([2,2])
```

If I want to place the row sums of `mat1` into the first row of `mat2`, I can do it like this:

```
np.sum(mat1, axis=1, out = mat2[0])

mat2
#array([[ 1.,  1.],
#       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

However, if I want to place the sums into the *diagonal indices* of `mat3`, I can't seem to do so.

```
np.sum(mat1, axis=1, out = mat3[np.diag_indices(2)])

mat3
#array([[ 0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

Of course, the following works, but I would like to use the `out` argument of `np.sum`

```
mat3[np.diag_indices(2)] = np.sum(mat1, axis=1)

mat3 
#array([[ 1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Can someone explain this behavior of the `out` argument not accepting the diagonal indices of an array as a valid output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy has two types of indexing: basic indexing and advanced indexing.

Basic indexing is what happens when your index expression uses only integers, slices, `...`, and `None` (a.k.a. `np.newaxis`). This can be implemented entirely through simple manipulation of offsets and strides, so when basic indexing returns an array, the resulting array is always a **view** of the original data. Writing to the view writes to the original array.

When you index with an array, as in `mat3[np.diag_indices(2)]`, you get advanced indexing. Advanced indexing cannot be done in a way that returns a view of the original data; it always **copies** data from the original array. That means that when you try to use the copy as an `out` parameter:

```
np.sum(mat1, axis=1, out = mat3[np.diag_indices(2)])
```

The data is placed into the copy, but the original array is unaffected.

---

We were supposed to have the ability to use `np.diagonal` for this by now, but even though the documentation says `np.diagonal`'s output is writeable in NumPy 1.10, the relevant feature for making it writable is [still in limbo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5407). It's probably best to just not use the `out` parameter for this:

```
mat3[np.diag_indices(2)] = np.sum(mat1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. it's a shame about not being able to use the `out` parameter. It would really save me a lot of headache!